# Finding particular value from a list by matching in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a small doubt in accessing the values from a list.
I have a list of elements

```
"result":[{"_id": "55b8b9913f32df094c7ba922", "Total": "450"}, 
          {"_id": "55b8a2083f32df1030b9ef16", "Total": "400"}]
```

Here we basically get values from a list by doing `list[0]` or something like this based on the no. of list elements.

I would like to know if we can get only the particular value from the list by matching it with the `_id`. Since if the database is large it would be difficult to get the values by doing `list[]`

My actual code is:

```
id = self.body['_id']
test = yield db.Result.aggregate(
        [
            { '$group': { '_id' : "$StudentId",
                'Total': {'$max': "$Total"}}
            }
        ]
    )
list = test.get('result')
print(list)
```

I would like to get the total of the provided `id` only.

Comment: Your "Total" field contains a "string". If you don't change that to be numeric you will get unexpected results. Strings sort differently to numbers. i.e "8" is greater that "100".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) first to just get the documents you want.

```
id = self.body['_id']

test = yield db.Result.aggregate(
        [
            { '$match': { '_id': id } },
            { '$group': { '_id' : "$StudentId",
                'Total': {'$max': "$Total"}}
            }
        ]
    )
list = test.get('result')
print(list)
```

And for multiple values to match, use [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/), declare an array

```
listOfIds = [id1,id2,id3]
```

And the pipeline change:

```
            { '$match': { '_id': { '$in': listOfIds } },
```

As I said earlier though:

> *Your "Total" field contains a "string". If you don't change that to be numeric you will get unexpected results. Strings sort differently to numbers. i.e "8" is greater that "100".*

So you really should change that in your data.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed my data to numeric in my database